# Parentheses while using ternary operator

Tags: java

Why is the output different for the two cases below? It was part of a bigger problem that I've debugged and narrowed down to the issue

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    

        String test = "hello";
        System.out.println(call() + test.charAt(0)=='h'?1:0);
    }

static int call()
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

> Output : 0

But if I add a paranthesis, I get the expected output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    

        String test = "hello";
        System.out.println(call() + (test.charAt(0)=='h'?1:0));
    }

static int call()
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

> Output : 2 (as expected)

In the initial call, is call() + test.charAt(0) evaluated against 'h', and assigned 1 and 0 accordingly? Which means {1 + ascii value of 'h'} == 105 is evaluated against ascii value of 'h' which is 104?

Comment: Read about [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: @AndyTurner, please no downvotes. I have pretty much figured out the solution my self. Answers below have been getting so many up votes, which means people are reading this question.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question.

Comment: @saltandwater I don't think Andy downvoted but I guess the downvote was because of no effort shown. Imho, it might be true since this needed a little research effor, however not a bad question hence my up

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, thanks for the reply. But no research effort? I have been able to fix it, and also suggested that it is due to 105, which is indeed the correct answer. Doesn't that count as research effort?

Comment: @saltandwater sorry, I mean that the downvote might be because of that (that's what the downvote tooltip says). But as I said, it was a valid and good question to me and that's why I gave my up

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, thanks for the upvote Federico. Appreciate it.

Comment: @saltandwater you have asked a question which you could easily answer yourself. You think that you're comparing 105 to `'h'`? Try it: change `'h'` to `'i'` (or 105), and see what happens. But again: I didn't downvote.

Comment: @AndyTurner, thanks Andy. I think I'm over the down vote :)
Part of the reason I asked the question, was because I wanted an online diary of my mistakes, which is why I even went ahead and answered it. Over it like I said, haha

Comment: @AndyTurner, and btw I did try various combinations before posting. Like for example, I changed the return value of call function to 0, and that went on to give me the correct answer since nothing is added. I really just wanted a clarification, and an online bank of this bug along with helping someone who's stuck with a similar problem. But, whatever! :)

Comment: Not related to what you are asking, but since you are creating an online bank of your mistakes, here is another: "ascii value of 'h'" Read [charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) and [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode); No mention of ASCII at all, which makes sense because a string is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually no problem, the operators have difference precedence order.

If you check the link that [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) added in his comment you will find this table

[image]

As you can see the `additive` (`+` and `-`) has higher precedence over the ternary operator.
This is why:

```
call() + test.charAt(0)=='h'?1:0
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  High precedence      
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       Less precedence
```

So, you can change the precedence order using parentheses:

```
call() + (test.charAt(0)=='h'?1:0)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              High precedence      
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       Less precedence
```

Answer (score 2):

The point is not your ternary operator, but the fact that `+` precedes `==`:

```
call() + test.charAt(0)=='h'?1:0
```

is in any reading equivalent to

```
(call() + test.charAt(0)) == 'h'?1:0
```

Also, `==` has higher precedence then `?`, so this is equal to

```
((call() + test.charAt(0)) == 'h') ? 1 : 0
```